# background video isnt taking up the entire screen on some devices

Tags: responsive-design

the background video isnt taking up the entire screen on some Ipads and mobile devices and the images that i made into buttons are partially cut off on the top with mobile view, im using bootstrap 5 and would greatly appreciate some help

> 

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    > <html lang="en">
    >   <head>
    >     <title>Title</title>
    > 
    >     <meta charset="utf-8" />
    >     <meta
    > name="viewport"
    > content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    >     />
    > 
    >     <link
    > rel="stylesheet"
    > href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    > integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
    > crossorigin="anonymous"
    >     />
    >     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    > 
    >     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    >     <link
    > href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lancelot:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
    > rel="stylesheet"
    >     />
    >   </head>
    >   <body>
    >     <style>
    >       .no-gutter > [class*="col-"] {
    > padding-right: 0px;
    > padding-left: 0px;
    >       }
    >     </style>
    > 
    >     <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted loop class="back_video">
    >       <source src="assets/trimmed rest foot.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    > Your browser does not support the video tag.
    >     </video>
    > 
    >     <div
    > class="container align-items-center d-flex custom-bg"
    > style="height: 100vh"
    >     >
    >       <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters">
    >         <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 align-items-center">
    >           <button class="img__wrapper">
    >             <img
    > src="assets/stock reserve.jpg"
    > class="img-fluid d-block project__img"
    >             />
    >             <div class="img__wrapper-bg"></div>
    >             <div class="img__discription">
    >               <h3 class="img__description--title">Reservation</h3>
    >             </div>
    >           </button>
    >         </div>
    > 
    >         <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 align-items-center">
    >           <button class="img__wrapper">
    >             <img
    > src="assets/stock menu.jpg"
    > class="img-fluid d-block project__img"
    >             />
    > 
    >             <div class="img__wrapper-bg"></div>
    >             <div class="img__discription">
    >               <h3 class="img__description--title">Menu</h3>
    >             </div>
    >           </button>
    >         </div>
    >       </div>
    >     </div>
    > 
    >     <script
    > src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    > integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    > crossorigin="anonymous"
    >     ></script>
    >     <script
    > src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    > integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    > crossorigin="anonymous"
    >     ></script>
    >     <script
    > src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    > integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    > crossorigin="anonymous"
    >     ></script>
    >   </body>
    > </html> 
    > 

```
CSS
```


> * {
> box-sizing: border-box;
> 
> }
> 
> 
> body {
> 
> font-family: 'Lancelot', cursive;
> font-weight: 500;
> }
> 
> 
> .back_video {
> position: absolute;
> right: 0;
> bottom: 0;
> z-index: -1;
> overflow: hidden;
> }
> 
> .project__img {
> width: 100%;
> scale: 1.1;
> }
> 
> 
> .img__wrapper {
> position: relative;
> box-shadow: 0 20px 80px 0 rgb(27, 27, 27);
> overflow: hidden;
> display: flex;
> justify-content: center;
>  align-content: center;
> }
> 
> .img__wrapper:hover .img__wrapper-bg {
> opacity: 0.7;
> }
> 
> .img__wrapper-bg {
> position: absolute;
> top: 0;
> left: 0;
> width: 100%;
> height: 100%;
> background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
> opacity: 0;
> transition: all 450ms ease-in-out;
> }
> 
> .img__wrapper:hover .img__discription{
> opacity: 1;
> transform: translateY(-50%);
> 
> }
> 
> .img__wrapper:hover .project__img {
> transform: scale(1.07);
> filter: blur(5px);
> transition: 400ms ease-in-out;
> }
> 
> .img__discription {
> position: absolute;
> top: 50%;
> transform: translateY(100%);
> opacity: 0;
> transition: opactiy 300ms, transform 450ms ease-in-out;
> color: black;
> max-width: 550px;
> 
> }
> 
> .img__description--title {
> font-size: 50px;
> color: white;
> }
````

‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Comment: https://github.com/scxmbxg/resturant_bootstrap.git the github repo